# How to extract string between quotes in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to extract the string between quotation marks in a file.

For example: my file is called `test.txt` and it has the following content:

```
"Hello_World"
```

I am reading it as follows from bash:

```
string="$(head -1 test.txt)"
echo $string
```

This prints `"Hello_World"`, but I need `Hello_World`.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your title does not match what you are asking at all?

Comment: This seems very contrived. There are (obviously, see below) lots of ways to do what you *ask*, but could you clarify the context and intent of the question? Must you read from a file into a variable? Is the file always one line? Are you trying to isolate and extract data from a more complex situation, or is this literally what you need? We can provide better solutions when we know the actual problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `tr`:

```
echo "$string " | tr -d '"'
```

From `man tr`:

> DESCRIPTION
>        The `tr` utility copies the standard input to the standard output with substitution or deletion of selected characters.
>
> The following options are available:
>
> ```
>  -C      Complement the set of characters in string1, that is ``-C ab'' includes every character except for `a' and `b'.
>
>  -c      Same as -C but complement the set of values in string1.
>
>  -d      Delete characters in string1 from the input.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in pure `bash` without having to spawn *any* external programs:

```
read -r line < test.txt ; line=${line#\"} ; line=${line%\"} ; echo $line
```

The `read` actually reads in the entire line, and the two assignments actually strip off any *single* quote at the start or end of the line.

I assumed you didn't want to strip out any quotes within the string itself so I've limited it to one at either end.

It also allows you to successfully read lines *without* a leading quote, trailing quote, or both.

Comment: You could just use `#\"` and `%\"`, as the notion of "longest match" doesn't make a lot of sense for a single character as the pattern.

Comment: Good point, @Benjamin, I'll change it. I guess the regex engine running in my own skull is just greedy by default :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use `sed` to read the first line and also filter out `"`, try following command,

```
sed -n '1 s/"//gp' test.txt
```

Brief explanation,

- `-n`: suppress automatic print
- `1`: Match only the first line
- `s/"//gp`: filter out `"`, and then print the line